# How to hide a image on app start in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

i am having  a image which has to be enabled only when a button is clicked! 
I know the code to enable and disable UI components.

```
component.enabled=false, component.enabled=true;
```

But the image is viewable on start of the app!

So how to hide the sprite on start of the app and show only when button is clicked?

Comment: It´s disabled the image on the start?, maybe its duplicated

Comment: Why not disable it as default via the inspector?

Comment: You should post your full UI code so we can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having your code would be usefull...

Disable the component or set inactive the whole gameobject inside an `Awake` function (avoid the `Start` function, unless the script responsible for the disabling of your image is on other gameobject

```
// C#
private UnityEngine.UI.Image image ;

private void Awake()
{
     image = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image>();

     HideImage();
}

public void HideImage()
{
     image.enabled = false ;

     // ===== OR =====

     gameObject.SetActive(false);
}

public void ShowImage()
{
     image.enabled = true;

     // ===== OR =====

     gameObject.SetActive(true);

}
```

To detect when a button is clicked, you can add a listener at runtime :

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

```
    UnityEngine.UI.Button btn = otherGameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
    btn.onClick.AddListener(ShowImage);
```

Comment: Thanks @Hellium !This is what i was looking for.. :)

Comment: Hi @hellium , I want to use 4 buttons with different targets, Every Target starts target on button click, I put button on screen But I don't know how to work this on button click and how to use script. Please help me